# How to remove a piece in a string

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I am making a quest system, and I want to randomly choose a quest, but i dont want it to choose the same one again.
Here is the piece on code for the string.
I cant find any good answer.
This is a more simple line of code.

```
string[] QuestChoose = new string[] {"Quest1", "Quest2", "Quest3"};
```

Answer (score 0):

3 methods come to mind:

- Convert to a List and call `Remove()`.
- Write null into the array after having read the quest and when selecting a quest, always search for the next suggestion if null was selected.
- Keep a separate data structure like a `HashSet<int>` where you add the index in the array whenever a quest has been used. Then check for Contains on your ID when selecting.

Comment: oh thanks, ill try it

Answer (score 0):

You really ought to use lists if you want to dynamically add/remove elements from your set.
Instead of:

```
string[] QuestChoose = new string[] {"Quest1", "Quest2", "Quest3"};
```

try using:

```
List<string> QuestChoose = new List<string> { "Quest1", "Quest2","Quest3"};
```

You can add elements by calling `QuestChoose.Add("Quest4");`
Or remove an element by calling: `QuestChoose.Remove(ItemNumber);`
Where as `"ItemNumber"` is the index of the string you want to remove. For example; Calling `QuestChoose.Remove(0);` will remove the first item in the list, which in this case would be `"Quest1"`

Comment: oh nice, thanks, it works